# How to deploy ASP.NET application in cloud

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud

Can any one explain what are the things we need to remember before deploying asp.net web application into cloud?.

Comment: -1 for not googling before coming here! There are tons of articles regarding these concerns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please find the following things:

1. Need to delete existing deployment package from the hosted application by using manage.windowsazure.com
2. Need to change local database  string to colud application database string in web.config or app.config
   3.Need to install caching by using "Manage NuGet Packages for solution" by right click on solution

Search for azure caching in "NuGet" Online search...  You will see "Windows Azure Caching"  then click on "Install" button

After cache installation  you will see the following content/commented content in web.config

< section name ="dataCacheClients " type=" Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation= "true" allowDefinition=" Everywhere" />
    < section name ="cacheDiagnostics " type=" Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon " allowLocation ="true " allowDefinition=" Everywhere" />

< dataCacheClient name ="default ">
      < autoDiscover isEnabled ="true " identifier ="[cache cluster role name] " />
      -->
    
  
  
    < crashDump dumpLevel ="Off " dumpStorageQuotaInMB ="100 " />

</providers>
    </sessionState> -->
    
    
      
        
          
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
    </caching> -->
 Uncomment above 2 commented sections(Session State, Caching)
 Need to change  identifier  value("[cache cluster role name] ")  under  autoDiscover element to  your project current role name.
ex: My project Role Name: MyRole.  then the identifier value will be "My Role";
 < autoDiscover isEnabled = "true " identifier = "MyRole " />

- Now go to web role configuration.
- Enable caching for web role. Then double click on azure role and you will see "Caching" option then check "Enable caching" and specify the storage account credentials

Check this link for caching info
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/

-Set all the References "Copy Local" property to True

To Enable Win 32 Bit  to your cloud application. Perform the following steps
- Add Enable32BitAppPool file to your project and  set "Copy to Output Directory " to  "Copy Always"

## Add the following task line in "ServiceDefinition.csdef" file under Startup section :

Import your colud profile to your application

- right click on  your azure project and click on publish you will see publish dialog
- If your already downloaded your cloud application settings click on import
- IF your not downloaded your cloud application settings click on "Sign in to download credentials" and download it and import it.
- Choose your subscription from the imported list.
- Click on next and ensure the cloud service and Check on "Enable Remote Desktop for all roles".
- Finally ensure all the configuration details and click on publish

Note: before starting publish. Close the other applications which consumes more virtual memory else you will get out of memory exception during the publish...

## To enable SSL to your application

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/

## Please check the following link:

http://mramasubbareddy.blogspot.in/2013/05/azure-deployment-things-to-remember.html

Comment: can you tell us why it is important (number 1 in your list) to delete the existing deployment prior to deploying new one? (ref.: `1. Need to delete existing deployment package from the hosted application by using manage.windowsazure.com`? I would rather argue that you shall never delete existing deployment package. Especially for production environments.

Comment: can you please tell me how can we deploy without deleting existing deployment copy?.

Comment: via [In-place update of a Windows Azure Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See this links its too long to discuss [Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/), [How to Create and Deploy a Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-cloud-service/)

Comment: They are explained very clearly thanks bot

Comment: Your welcome. If I have time I will include the full explanation in my answer. I'm also currently hosting my site to windows azure. :)

Comment: Btw could you accept this as an answer? thanks :)